# Qubit in Type 1.5 superconductor?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, superconductivity, anyons

I'm interested in Type 1.5 superconductors, first proposed by Egor Babaev in 2002 and found in the laboratory in 2009 (magnesium dibromide).  Such conductors favor small bundles of vortices.  The most stable number of vortices in the bundle varies depending on conditions but is typically from 2 to 12.  The vortices have fractional quanta.  The bundle is sheathed by larger vortex.

Lets suppose that we have a bundle of three.  Would each vortex be an anyon, and the bundle be a qubit?